# Multi-line title with variable in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, title

I'm using Matplotlib 3.1.2 and I'm trying to have a title that is split into two lines. I have a variable string in the `plt.title()` with latex formatting (r''). When I try the `\newline` or `\n` inside the string the output simply prints the \newline or \n as text and there's no line split. Here's my implementation:

```
  plt.title(r'M$_{\rm{BH}}$ = 10$^{10}$ M$_{\odot}$, log U = %s, r$_{\rm{in}}$ = 10$^{18}$ cm'%(-1 + ((array1.tolist().index(i))*0.25)))
```

I tried adding a `plt.suptitle()` which does the job but there's an overlap between the two lines and I don't know how to add spacing/padding between them.

Comment: I think `\n` is not interpreted as a new line for a raw string. A workaround is to breakdown your string in sub-strings, separated by + '\n' + .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is not to use raw-strings, but you need to escape the `\`:

```
plt.title('M$_{\\rm{BH}}$ = 10$^{10}$ M$_{\\odot}$\nlog U = %s\nr$_{\\rm{in}}$ = 10$^{18}$ cm'%('test'))
```

[image]

Comment: A simpler example: `import matplotlib.pylot as plt`, then `plt.title("testing\nmultiple\nlines")`, and then finally `plt.show()`

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a solution to this and got it working even with raw strings for LaTeX using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.title(r"Text $\omega$" + '\n' + r"$\delta$", multialignment='center')
```

or, with 3D plots:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_title(r"Text $\omega$" + '\n' + r"$\delta$", multialignment='center')
```

It may or may not be necessary to use actual LaTeX rendering of text instead of Matplotlib's built-in MathTex. You can do this by:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams.update({"text.usetex" : True})
```

Plus, I think it looks far nicer with it.