# How to make a multiline title with strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, title, hashable

I am new to using Python and am converting some of my MatLab code. I have 3 strings that I would like to use as a multi-line title. I keep getting the error"TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'".

```
# importing the required module 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    
# x axis values 
x = [1,2,3] 
# corresponding y axis values 
y = [2,4,1] 

wx = 1
wy = 2
wz = 3
v0 = 50

# Create title strings:
line1 = ['Position']
line2 = ['$w_x =$ ',str(wx),' ft/s, $w_y =$ ', str(wy),' ft/s,  $w_z =$ ', str(wz),' ft/s']
line3 = ['$V_0$ = ',str(v0),' ft/sec'] 

# plotting the points  
plt.plot(x, y) 
    
# naming the x axis 
plt.xlabel('x - axis') 
# naming the y axis 
plt.ylabel('y - axis') 
    
# giving a title to my graph 
plt.title({line1, line2, line3})
    
# function to show the plot 
plt.show()
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi-line title with variable in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59982202/multi-line-title-with-variable-in-matplotlib)

Comment: You should also get familiar with [f-string formatting](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). It makes many things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    
# x axis values 
x = [1,2,3] 
# corresponding y axis values 
y = [2,4,1] 

wx = 1
wy = 2
wz = 3
v0 = 50

# Create title strings:
line1 = ['Position', '\n']
line2 = ['$w_x =$ ',str(wx),' ft/s, $w_y =$ ', str(wy),' ft/s,  $w_z =$ ', str(wz),' ft/s', '\n']
line3 = ['$V_0$ = ',str(v0),' ft/sec', '\n']

# plotting the points  
plt.plot(x, y) 
    
# naming the x axis 
plt.xlabel('x - axis') 
# naming the y axis 
plt.ylabel('y - axis') 
    
# giving a title to my graph 
title = ''
for i in line1: title += i + ' '
title += '\n'
for i in line2: title += i + ' '
title += '\n'
for i in line3: title += i + ' '
plt.title(title)
    
# function to show the plot 
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]